Meaning of mount command parameters
I'm trying to mount a NAS to a coding environment.
I found that this command is needed but i don't know the details of it.
Can anyone explain what do file_mode=0777, dir_mode, uid and gid mean ? in:
rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,credentials=/config/cred,uid=$(id −u),gid =$(id -g),vers=3.0


Please be aware that uid=$(id −u) will not work as expected due to the long dash which is used here. Instead, you should use uid=$(id -u).

That is not a command in itself, but the value of the -o (options) parameter to the mount command used. So the command would be:
mount [device] [mount point] -t [fs type] -o rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,credentials=/config/cred,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),vers=3.0

where [device] is the NAS as seen by your OS, [mount point] is the directory that you want to NAS to be mounted under, and [fs type] is the filesystem type of your NAS. We don't know what filesystem your NAS is, but it could very well be cifs (for a Samba type share), as the following parameters suggest a cifs filesystem.
file_mode is the set of permissions that newly created files on the NAS (created through the mount) will get. These would be readable, writable and executable by any user. This may be a security risk, but that is up to you.
dir_mode is the same as file_mode but for new directories.
The uid and gid are the user IDs and group IDs that the NAS will use to access the files. User IDs and group IDs are numbers. That means that these numbers should be defined in the NAS as valid users. The value that is passed to the NAS as user ID in this specific command is the result of the command id -u, i.e. the ID of the user who executes the mount command. That would be 1000 on most systems. Same for the group ID which is passed as id -g.
Also, a credentials file is passed. This is usually used to contain the username and password to access the NAS. Note that the username in the credentials file may conflict with the uid parameter. I don't know which one gets to be used if they point to different users. Better omit one of these.
All of this information can be learned from man mount and additional man files, such as man mount.cifs.

@mook765 Well spotted, thanks

Thanks @Raffa, edited

You are welcome Jos, it’s not your typing mistake :) but rather OP's look at the question … OP probably add spaces not knowing it will break their fstab line … That’s what I should have stated clearly in my earlier comment … apologies

many thanks for the explanations. Yet, I have following issue when trying to mount the NAS ;
mount error(115): Operation now in progress
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
[17633659.512448] CIFS: Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
[17633659.512466] CIFS: VFS: \xx.xxxx.xxx Send error in SessSetup = -13
dmesg shows this:
Any clue on this ?

Do you have the cifs-utils package installed on the client? Have you checked whether the UID and GID that you use are defined on the server, and consistent with the credentials file? If yes and yes, perhaps you should open a separate question.

Explanation for some of them:
rw is for mounting file system with read and write permissions
file_mode=0777 sets permissions for files (r/w/x)
dir_mode=0777: sets permissions for directories
uid=$(id -u): means owner's user ID is the same as current user's ID
credentials=/config/cred: means credentials file are at /config/cred
Not sure about the rest.

The file mode sets the LOCAL file permissions, and dir mode does the same for directories. uid (user identifier) and gid (group identifier) set the respective LOCAL owners for these objects. This is only a mask on how the files will appear on the client side, it does not change the files and folders on the server.
I'll just blatantly assume we are talking about SMB mounts here as these are the most common and easiest to setup.
There are a few things here that decide what is the exact file behaviour. It roughly works like this:
on the server side (for example Samba) you set:

what is shared
what is allowed as maximum permission (read-only, or read/write)
what are the permissions of newly added files (create_mask & directory_mask)
who is allowed to login to this share

quick example of a samba config file snippet:
[shared]
   path = /srv/samba/test
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   guest ok = no
   create mask = 0664
   directory mask = 0775
   valid users = @smbgroup

These server settings only control file behavior on the server side, they do not impact how the files behave on your local client computer.
When you mount such a share the server exposes all the original owner and permission information to the client, however, these will probably not work for the system that you are accessing these files from. So when mounting this on the client you will mask these with something that allows your local user(s) to work with the files correctly.
example:
you login to your client computer as user: JohnDoe
your user account on the server might be: JDoe
and the files you try to access might be created by user: SuperMan
(BTW: your own files on the server are therefore owned by user: JDoe)
so when you mount the share on your local machine you should use the uid and gid mask to the uid of your local user JohnDoe and the gid to some group this user is member of on your local system. This makes you the local owner of these files (but ONLY on your local system, it's a mask). Otherwise you would not even be able to work with your own files on the server as the server user is a different one as your local account on your client computer.
And for the same reason you can overwrite the local file and directory permissions. This way you can overcome permission problems for example with groups, or other users. I personally mostly use 664 for files and 775 for directories.
Finally: I think that umask settings your server system might also impact how the permissions of new files are created. out of scope for this answer but something to keep in the back of your mind in case you start to see things that do not make sense. Bonus information as you will :)
